# Recapturing Strong References to Weakly Referenced Objects Inside Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I am a Obj-C programmer who was born, and has only lived in a post ARC world. For my own efficacy though, I recently decided to go through Apple's *[Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)*. In the *[ARC Introduces New Lifetime Qualifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)* section, there is a subsection titled *Use Lifetime Qualifiers to Avoid Strong Reference Cycles* that describes various ways to use qualifiers in potential in order to avoid potential retain cycles.

My question has to do with the last two examples. The first of the last two examples uses a pattern that I often utilize in order to avoid deallocating a UIKit object prematurely from a non-main thread:

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];
// ...
MyViewController * __weak weakMyViewController = myController;
myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    [weakMyViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
};
```

In the above example, the `weakMyViewController` object is created with a weak reference to `myController` so that the block referencing `weakMyViewController` can use it, and upon return of the block, `weakMyViewController` can safely fall out of scope without decrementing the reference count of the underlying UIKit object being referenced.

In the next example though, Apple shows the following code for "non-trivial cycles":

```
MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];
// ...
MyViewController * __weak weakMyController = myController;
myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    MyViewController *strongMyController = weakMyController;
    if (strongMyController) {
        // ...
        [strongMyController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        // ...
    }
    else {
        // Probably nothing...
    }
};
```

In the above "non-trivial" example offered, the same `__weak` qualifier is used to reference the UIKit object from within the block, but then the code creates an local implicit `__strong` reference to the same object. Then that local `__strong` reference is tested for a non-nil condition, and is then operated on.

My two questions are:

1. Under what considerations should an Obj-C programmer implement the second design pattern (as opposed the former)? I don't understand Apple's comment about "non-trivial cycles"
2. How does the `__strong` reference to `weakMyController` not increment the retain count of the original `myController` object? If `weakMyController` is only a pointer to the underlying object that `myController` points to, wouldn't a strong pointer (i.e. `stringMyController`) increment the retain count of the underlying object (the object that `myController` is pointing to)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your first example, the motivation you ascribe to having the block literal only keep a `weak` reference to the instance pointed to by `myController` is not quite correct. `weak` references won't stop an object from deallocating, and the purpose of the weak reference is to prevent a strong reference cycle (also called a retain cycle). In this situation, the strong reference cycle would be manifested by `myController` maintaining a strong reference to the block stored in `completionHandler`, while the block maintains a strong reference back to `myController` - neither would ever be deallocated (without un-setting the `completionHandler` property at some future time). Thus, the motivation here is quite the opposite of keeping an object alive - it's to allow `myController` to deallocate normally when all other references to it cease to exist.

The second example is an extension of the first, but by assigning the captured weak reference to a strong reference local to the block, we can ensure that so long as the controller is still alive when block execution begins, it will remain alive until the end of block execution. Since the strong reference is scoped only to the block, it doesn't create a strong reference cycle. In other words, `strongMyController` is local only to the scope of the block's code, and is not retained by the block object itself.

Now, to address your specific questions:

1. You would take this approach when you want to ensure the block completes execution with a reference to a live, non-nil object from its enclosing scope, if that object was alive when the block begins execution. If there's a chance that all other strong references to an object may disappear during execution of the block, you should seriously consider using this.
2. The strong reference certainly does increment the reference count, and is the point - while the scope of the block's code is active, the controller will be kept alive. This does not form a strong reference cycle since, again, it's not the block object that maintains the reference, but the variable used in the block's code, which only exists when the block is executing. Assuming the block does not continue execution to infinity, then the cycle will be broken.

Comment: To be a little more precise (i.e. nitpick ;-), but as we're seeking understanding...), the last sentence isn't quite correct: a strong reference cycle *is* created but is broken when the block finishes. Cycles *per se* are not bad, just those that prevent reclamation of unneeded objects. In this case the cycle is important, if all other references to the controller are removed while the block is executing the cycle keeps it alive until the block finishes.

Comment: @CRD `strongMyController` is an automatic variable local to the block body's scope but isn't retained by the block object itself. While it does establish a strong reference to the VC when in the stack frame for the block's function, it's not really a cycle because it's not owned by the block, instead its lifetime is bound to the stack frame of the associated block function. BUt you are correct in emphasizing that the strong reference keeps the vc alive until the end of the execution.

Comment: Yes, I think you win ;-) There is a disconnect between the block and the stack frame so it's not actually a cycle but just another reference - which keeps the VC alive if required.

Comment: Thank you both for the help here. Crystal clear now. One of those thing you have to read a couple times over to fully grasp. My poorly worded earlier comment about keeping a weak reference was in the context of capturing a VC with a strong reference in a block that is scheduled to run on a thread that is not the main thread - TN -"Deallocation Problem". Always keeping a weak ref so that the VC's dealloc isn't called from a diff thread. That wouldn't be an issue here because, presumably, the completion block for a VC (UI Kit obj) would always be called from the main thread.

Comment: @TaylorHalliday I apologize for the lack of clarity in my answer. I have edited it to hopefully be more clearly worded and specific. I'm not totally sure what you're referring to by *TN - "Deallocation Problem"*, though. And, could you share more info on the need to prevent `dealloc` from being called on another thread, that is, the need to prevent an asynchronous block from holding the last strong reference to a view controller?

Comment: @CarlVeazey No - you were solid. Here is the Apple Technical Note ('TN') I was referring to: [Technical Note TN 2109](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2109/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010274-CH1-SUBSECTION11) Third major bullet point down was where I was getting tripped up. If you dispatch a block onto a another thread for some work and don't guard against a dealloc from that secondary thread.

Comment: ReactiveCocoa has some tricksy macros called `@weakify` and `@strongify` that cast the passed variable to a `__weak` or `__strong` variable at the same name as the original variable (i.e. it's shadowed) (the macros include a bit of clang pragmas to silence the shadow warning). [Here's the file they declare them in](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/extobjc/EXTScope.h)